# Firefox not playing embedded swf

Tags: html, firefox, flash

I am using swfin to embed a swf object (video player) and it loads fine in all browsers, but in firefox it won't "start".  I have to right click on the movie area and "start" is unchecked so I click on "start" and it will start just fine.  Yet, in chrome and IE (haven't moved to a mac for testing yet) it fires up and starts just as I expected.  I have tried swfobject instead of swfin and I have IE issues that I couldn't seem to correct.  Hence moving to swfin.  I saw a similiar problem like this using swfobject but I can't get it to replicate anymore.

Here is the swfin code:
`

```
     var s = new swfIN("/Flash/video_player_playhead_overlays.swf", "flashMovie", "427", "280");
     // s.hideSEO("div_seo");
     s.addVar("video_file", "/DownloadableWork/Boardwalk.flv");
     s.addVar("poster_file", "/Images/UploadedImages/Boardwalk.jpg");
     s.addVar("clock_display", "yes");
     s.addVar("playbtn_scale", "1");

     s.addParam("play", "true");
     s.addParam("loop", "true");
     s.addParam("quality", "high");
     s.addParam("scale", "showall");
     s.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
     s.addParam("menu", "true");

     s.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "sameDomain");

     s.write();
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to the video player swf itself rather than the http browser.

I would strongly recommend using swfobject, it's widely accepted as the industry standard for embedding swf content.

http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/

SWFObject is also recommended by Adobe.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html